# Storyboard UIView Objects Not Instantiating

Tags: swift, storyboard, instantiation

I am working on a project with Swift and Storyboards.  It's a conversion project from a traditional IB and Objective-C project.  I am having an issue with a UITableView instantiating when the view is loaded.  Let me explain.

The project is a navigation project.  Here is an overview of the Storyboard.

[image]

The Storyboard's first viewController is HomeViewController and is a landing page that displays general info.  The next VC is called FeedViewController shows a number of RSS feeds.  You can see an expanded screen shot of the NavigationController, HomeViewController and FeedViewController in the picture below.

[image]

My problem is that I can't get the tableView to Instantiate.  I first checked to make sure that my tableView was connected as an outlet and that the dataSource and delegate properties were connected.  You can see this in the pic below.

[image]

In my FeedViewController class I have an Outler property called feedsTableView.  You can see the declaration in the code below.

```
    class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FLODataHandlerDelegate
{
    // View Contoller and Protocol Properties
    var floView : FLOViewController?
    var dataHandler : FLODataHandler?

    // Interface and Content Properties
    var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl?

    // IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var feedsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
```

In the HomeViewController I have a FeedViewController property that I intend to use to gain access to FeedViewController's feedsTableView.

```
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController, FLODataHandlerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
    // View Contoller and Protocol Properties
    var feedViewController : FeedViewController?
    var dataHandler : FLODataHandler?
```

When HomeViewController's viewDidLoad() method is called I start the dataHandler - which instantiates the FeedViewController - and set it to my FeedViewController property.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up the gesture recognizer to allow for swiping to the feed VC.
    let recognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("goToNext"))
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    // Start the data handler
    self.setUpDataHandler()
}
```

setUpDataHandler()

```
func setUpDataHandler()
    {
        // Intitalize FeedVC for use later in the VC
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FeedViewController") as! FeedViewController
        self.feedViewController = vc
    }
```

I also have a fail safe that if someone were to go to the FeedViewController before the setUpDataHandler() method is called then I instantiate FeedViewController here as well.

```
func goToNext()
{
    // Grab the feedViewController so it can be pushed onto the stack.  Make sure you set up the storyboard identifier.
    let feedVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FeedViewController") as! FeedViewController
    self.feedViewController = feedVC
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.feedViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

However the feedsTableView is not getting instantiated.  In the viewDidLoad() method of FeedViewController I attempt to add the feedsTableView to a UIRefreshController.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refreshInvoked:state:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    // See the note in viewDidLoad in FLOViewController.
    self.feedsTableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl!)
}
```

When the app runs I get the following error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The image below shows were this is called.  It's the viewDidLoad() of the FeedViewController.  As you can see in the picture I even tried instantiating the feedsTableView before adding it to the UIRefreshController and I still get the error.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Take care,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work in the very last case, where you manually instantiate UITableView and assign that to `self.feedsTableView`, is that `self.feedsTableView` is declared `weak`. Thus, the table view comes into existence, is assigned, and vanishes in a puff of smoke because it has no memory management. By the time you get to the last line, `self.feedsTableView` is `nil` once again.

Thus, the solution for that last case is to remove the `weak` designation from your `feedsTableView` declaration.

That will get you past the crash in that last case. But of course you won't see anything because you are not also inserting the table view into your interface.

Comment: I can't explain the base case, though, because I don't understand your view controller structure in the storyboard: too weird for my blood.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work.  I removed the weak declaration and it did not correct the issue.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: I _said_ it wouldn't solve it. I was only talking about that last desperate attempt where you instantiate manually.